# Facebook Graph API - Force Minimum Version?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When Facebook depreciated Graph API v1.0 they provided a switch in the application settings to force the application to use Graph API v2.0.  This greatly simplified testing of the application before v1.0 was depreciated.

I'm now in the process of updating an application to support a more recent version of the Graph API and would really like to be able to force the application to use a minimum Graph API version for testing purposes but there doesn't seem to be any way to do so.

I have versioned many of my calls so that I can set the Graph API version, but that won't catch problems such as the depreciation of FQL in v2.1.

Does anyone know of an overall way to force a Facebook application to use a minimum Graph API for testing purposes before the current API is depreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened upon a solution when I was creating test users for my application.

Facebook has added an *API Version to Install* setting that is shown if you select Yes for *Authorize Test Users for This App?*

I hope someone else in the same situation finds this useful.

[image: Create Test User]